# How to vectorize a function to work within data.table assignment

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(reg=letters[c(2:4)],list_reg_size=c(2:4))
   reg list_reg_size
1:   b             2
2:   c             3
3:   d             4
```

I wrote the following function that nests a char vector inside a new column list_dt:

```
create_list <- function(dt){
  dt[,list_dt:=list(letters[1:list_reg_size])]
}
```

that provides the correct output for a single element, appending a column containing a nested list to the input :

```
(subset <- dt[1])
   reg list_reg_size
1:   b             2

create_list(subset)
subset
   reg list_reg_size list_dt
1:   b             2     a,b
```

Please note that the size of the list varies with list_reg_size of each row, such as the desired result for dt would be:

```
create_list(dt))
dt
reg list_reg_size list_dt
1:   b             2     a,b
2:   c             3     a,b,c
3:   d             4     a,b,c,d
```

However, when I run the code above I get:

```
   reg list_reg_size list_dt
1:   b             2     a,b
2:   c             3     a,b
3:   d             4     a,b
```

I tried `lapply(dt, create_list)` that throws an error:

```
Error in `:=`(list_dt, list(letters[1:list_reg_size])) : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

How do I vectorize this function to get the desired output? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to solve your problem in base R. Not `data table`, I know, but it might be useful:

```
df <- data.frame(reg=letters[c(2:4)],list_reg_size=c(2:4),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

create_list <- function(list_reg_size){
 list(letters[1:list_reg_size])
}
```

**UPDATE**

As @chinsoon12 pointed out, one can use

```
setDT(df)[,list_dt:=sapply(list_reg_size, function(n) list(letters[seq_len(n)]))]
```

for `data.table`.

Comment: Yeah in data.table it will be setDT(df)[,list_dt:=sapply(list_reg_size, function(n) list(letters[seq_len(n)]))]

Answer (score 2):

In `data.table`, you can also do:

```
dt[, list(list_dt = paste(letters[1:list_reg_size], collapse = ",")), 
          by = c("reg", "list_reg_size")]
```